# Auto shutdown after about 15 minutes

Tags: shutdown, htc-dream, 2.3.3-gingerbread

I have a HTC G1 Dream device. I noticed that it has a problem. 

When I unplug it from charger, about 15 minutes later it shuts down.

Is there any solution for this?

P.S Factory reset won't help here. I've tried this about 3 times.

Comment: Does it shutdown and you have to turn it back on? Or is shutting down cause the battery drains? Does it still have the factory battery in it? Over the years batteries tend to wear out from charging and discharging over and over. And just because it shows it has 100% charge, Doesn't necessary mean that it is truly at 100%. And since that phone came out in mid 2009. If I was a betting man, I would say you need a new battery.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad battery, use logcat or a battery monitor and see what happens when it shutdown.

I had a device that would do the same but it would last 2 hours instead and under load would go about 5 mins :p
A new battery sorted it out in the end. But if you can get a new phone as once the battery starts to go the other compentnets will fail as well. If you cannot afford to do by a new phone at least backup on TB on a EXTERNAL SDCARD. so if worse comes to worst you have all the data for all your apps.